# How to track a flow of a c program?

Tags: c, testing, program-flow

I'ts more of a general question: how to handle the execution path of a c program, which consist of multiple functions?
For example, i have a following c program:

```
 void test_if_statement(int num)
{
    if (num > 0)
        //do smth
        ;
    else
        //do smth else
        ;
}

int main(void)
{
    int num;
    printf("enter an int value:");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    test_if_statement(num);
    return 0;
}
```

Currently i'm using something like this to see where did my function go in if statements:

```
void test_if_statement(int num)
{
        if (num > 0)
            printf("i'm here\n");
            //do smth
        
        else
            printf("now i'm there\n");
            //do smth else
}
```

How can I keep it simple and more universal?;)
Putting printf in every if-else pair seems unreasonably bulky...

Comment: Have a look into using a debugger, which allows you to run through the program line by line and see the values of different variables.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong using `printf` statements to track or log program flow for the purpose of learning, or testing during development.  But a good debugger will probably serve the purpose just as well without having to add in-line code.
Depending on your environment there is [a large list of debugger options available](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_debuggers).

Following is an overview of [debugging programs](https://www.cs.utah.edu/%7Egermain/PPS/Topics/debugging_programs.html):

> A debugger is a program that allows you to step through another
> program one line at a time. This is very useful when trying to
> identify incorrect code and analyze how a program "flows". Key
> concepts include: Breakpoints, Stepping, and Viewing data.

Key things that you can use the debugger to determine are:

> - The flow of the program (what happens next on a line by line basis)
> - The creation of variables
> - The data being stored in each variable
> - The entering/leaving of functions
> - The calculations that are made
> - The entering of IF statements or ELSE statements
> - The LOOPING of code.

[Much more detail here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debugger)

Answer (score 0):

This is usually a job for a *debugger*, most of which allow to step through the code one statement at a time.  They also allow you to set breakpoints to pause execution at specific locations, watchpoints that pause execution when a variable changes, etc.

Without knowing your environment I can’t recommend a specific debugger to use.  If you’re building code with gcc, then the companion debugger is (usually) gdb.  You will need to use the `-g` flag when compiling to enable source-code level debugging.  It’s not the friendliest debugger to use, but it’s pretty comprehensive.  If you’re building in the Visual Studio environment on Windows, there should be a debugger as part of the IDE.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an IDE for purpose of writing code then it would have built-in facilities for debuggers, the only thing you would need to do is set break-points and then when the program is run your code would pause whenever a break-point is hit. IDEs also provide facilities to look up variable values at that instant.

If you are not using an IDE and your question is specifically w.r.t `C` you could consider using `GDB`. Have a look [here](https://u.osu.edu/cstutorials/2018/09/28/how-to-debug-c-program-using-gdb-in-6-simple-steps/) to get a better idea of how to use GDB to debug programs.